# Checking out an old revision with externals

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm fairly new to SVN Tortoise, and I'm having some trouble understanding the combination of revisions and externals.

The SVN project I'm working on has several externals. Some of them are tags and a few point to the trunk of other SVN library projects.

When I try to roll back and look at an older revision of the project, it seems like what I check out is not exactly as it was a few weeks ago. The externals that point to the trunk of a library project are not rolled back, but contain the newest changes.

Should all externals point to tags of other projects, and if they don't, does it mean that you can't easily get a snapshot of a previous revision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I try to roll back and look at an older revision of the project, it seems like what I check out is not exactly as it was a few weeks ago

Yes. If externals-definition have not PEG-revision in it, SVN operates "as written" for historical states, without any additional heuristic like "which revision *was* HEAD for revision REV in main-project", and use today's data

> Should all externals point to tags of other projects

They *can*, not should. But you can also read about PEG|Operative revisions in SVN, and use PEG-specs in mutable-targets (and update definitions when new commits will appear in target)

Just compare these two definitions

```
Properties on 'tags\1.0.1':
  svn:externals
    -r 2 https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib@2 lib
```

Even if `/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib` will have additional commits later, external project with such definition will get always revision 2

```
Properties on 'trunk':
  svn:externals
    https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib lib
```

And for this definition older revisions of trunk will not restore existing state of `lib` automatically, you have to do it by hand

> if they don't, does it mean that you can't easily get a snapshot of a previous revision?

Definitely **yes** (if "easily" for you is pure `svn up REV` in super-repo)

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.