# Using svn externals with pegged revisions. How to branch from this revision

Tags: svn, tags, branch

I have a trunk in subversion (representing the project folder of my visual studio project). In that trunk I referenced some other projects via svn-externals. This works as expected. 
I can copy the whole trunk to a tag and thus make a tagged version out of my trunk. The svn-externals are being pegged to the head revisions after i copied the trunk to the tag.

Now I have the situation, that I want to branch a previous tag to change something for a specific customer. But when I copy the tag to the branch the pegged externals remain the same, and I cannot make changes to the repository any more. How am i supposed to branch such a tag?

Greetings Wolfgang

Comment: I do not able to parse the question completely. 1) Does copying trunk to a tag mean the revisions of the externals are pegged to their exact values at the time of the copy? 2) Do I understand correctly that you want to fork a branch off the tag you've created on step 1? 3) What is exactly wrong with the externals after such copying (assuming (2) is correct)? The externals remain at the pegged revisions, but you want them to be as fresh as possible,—or the other way round—they are as fresh as possible but you want them stuck at the revisions they were at at the time of tagging?

Comment: 1) After copying the trunk to a tag, I peg the externals revision to the one of the time of the copy. 2) yes. 3) IIRC, I was not able to commit the branch after editing it. That was the only problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post [Checking out an old revision with externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695513/checking-out-an-old-revision-with-externals?rq=1) adresses the same problem.
I have to take care that all externals are pegged to their respective revision when tagging the trunk.